# dynamic gif thumbnails

Tags: php, html, gif, animated-gif

So lets say I have 10 animated gifs in my folder in my server.

I am wanting to generate non animated thumbnails for these gifs. How can I do this dynamically without having to save any thumbnails into folders.

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you want to persist the thumbnails to disk? This is definitely the kind of thing you should be caching rather than regenerating every request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imagemagick is one option, GD library is already bundled with PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php

By not saving the image be aware that your script could end up being a resource hog. It may also choke on larger images.